# Matlab Psychtoolbox keeps crashing when running complex scripts

Tags: matlab, crash

I'm running psychtoolbox-3.0.10 in MATLAB R2011B in a Windows XP partition in a Macbook computer. I've been trying to run a script a Matlab for behavioral sciences course (see [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/ionefine/html/Psychtoolbox.html). The file is called `FunkyScreen.m`.

It works for first 30 seconds (the first 80 lines or so) and then Matlab suddenly crashes and closes. I clicked on the 'details' button of the message and it shows me that the program probably stopped because of the `mex` files.

#### Questions:

- Should I manually setup Matlab to compile those files?
- Or is it just crashing because of internal problems?

#### The script is:

```
% FunkyScreen.m
%
% opens a window using psychtoolbox,
% makes the window do some funky things
%
% written for Psychtoolbox 3 on the PC by IF 3/2007
screenNum=0;
flipSpd=13;% a flip every 13 frames
[wPtr,rect]=Screen('OpenWindow',screenNum);
monitorFlipInterval=Screen('GetFlipInterval', wPtr); 
% 1/monitorFlipInterval is the frame rate of the monitor
black=BlackIndex(wPtr);
white=WhiteIndex(wPtr);
% blank the Screen and wait a second
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
Screen(wPtr,'Flip');
HideCursor;
tic
while toc<1;
end
% make a rectangle in the middle of the screen flip colors and size
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip');% collect the time for the first flip with vbl
for i=1:10
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,[0 0 255], [100 150 200 250]);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
% flip 13 frames after vbl
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,[255 0 0], [100 150 400 450]);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
end
% blank the screen and wait a second
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
tic
while toc<1;
end
% make circles flip colors & size
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip');
for i=1:10
Screen('FillOval',wPtr,[0 180 255], [ 500 500 600 600]);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
Screen('FillOval',wPtr,[0 255 0], [ 400 400 900 700]);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
end
% blank the Screen and wait a second
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
tic
while toc<1;
end
% make lines that flip colors size & position
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip');
for i=1:10
Screen('DrawLine',wPtr,[0 255 255], 500, 200, 700 ,600, 5);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
Screen('DrawLine',wPtr,[255 255 0], 100, 600, 600 ,100, 5);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
end
% blank the Screen and wait a second
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
tic
while toc<1;
end
% combine the stimuli
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip');
for i=1:10
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,[0 0 255], [100 150 200 250]);
Screen('DrawLine',wPtr,[0 255 255], 500, 200, 700 ,600, 5);
Screen('FillOval',wPtr,[0 180 255], [ 500 500 600 600]);
Screen('TextSize', wPtr , 150);
Screen('DrawText', wPtr, 'FUNKY!!', 200, 20, [255 50 255]);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,[255 0 0], [100 150 400 450]);
Screen('FillOval',wPtr,[0 255 0], [ 400 400 900 700]);
Screen('DrawLine',wPtr,[255 255 0], 100, 600, 600 ,100, 5);
vbl=Screen(wPtr, 'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
end
% blank the screen and wait a second
Screen('FillRect',wPtr,black);
vbl=Screen(wPtr,'Flip', vbl+(flipSpd*monitorFlipInterval));
tic
while toc<1;
end
Screen('CloseAll');
ShowCursor
```

Comment: what's up with the while toc<1 line?  If toc ever ends up being >1 then that while loop will never terminate.  Wit some debugging, you could find exactly which line it gets stuck on, too, and point it out to us.  That would be helpful.

Comment: Oh I see... it keeps checking toc, which is measuring the temporal distance from tic, to make sure the program pauses for 1 second?  There's a pause command that you can hand the argument, 1: pause(1).  Not sure if the while toc will cause problems or not, I've had weird stuff happen with save+graphics in MATLAB: I try to save a figure after plotting (in code) but the save line comes to fast and the graphics haven't completely loaded so it errors out.  Of course, could have nothing to do with your problem, but I had to use a pause command to give the graphics time to load.

Comment: I recommend narrowing it down to a simpler, reproducible use case.  Asking people to wade through the first "80 lines or so" of code is asking quite a bit.  Also, do you know which lines call "the mex-file?" Do they crash on the first invocation of the MEX-file, or on a subsequent invocation?  The answer to that last question will do a lot to help address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can (probably) eliminate the problem.

```
Step 1: Run the code, try to get an indication of where it crashes
Step 2: Possibly using the information from Step 1, devide your code in 2 halves.
Step 3: Run both halves separately, see which one crashes
Step 4: Keep repeating the steps above untill you have identified the culprit 
Step 5: Try to deal with the specific problem that is found
```